# Stop a referenced dll from running migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a solution with a web application. This application uses Entity Framework and Code First. Then I have a second project, a console application. This console application shares the assembly that hold the migrations.

Is there a way to this console application that it should never run the Migrations? It could happen that this console application would contain a newer version which has not yet been deployed in the web application. I like to make sure there is no risk for the console to ruin the web application. Better to just have the console failing that updating the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the database initialiser to null in your `DbContext` constructor:

```
public class ConsoleContext : DbContext
{      public ConsoleContext()
        : base("Name=" + Config.ConnectionStringName)
    {
        // Prevent attempt to initialize a database for this context
        Database.SetInitializer<DtoContext>(null);
    }
}
```

Alternatively,
in your web application:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(
       new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
}
```

and in your console application:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<DtoContext>(null);
}
```

And, to be doubly certain, use two different database users. The web application will need `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter` and `db_ddladmin` roles if you're using Sql Server. The console application should only be in `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles to prevent it changing the database schema

Comment: I´m using the original context to inject into a another class so this wont work

Comment: You could use a different connection string in the console application with a different database user that only has read/write permissions

Comment: Yes I was just playing with that idea. Still interested to see if there other ways

Comment: I tried the Database.SetInitializer<DtoContext>(null); but it did not abort the migrations when tested. Will stick to the user with less rights.

Comment: Surely you must be calling `SetInitializer` somewhere else then?

Comment: Yes in the project containing the Entity Framework part it is set to "MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.." but the override of this in console part does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Easy) Yes, I have a good solution for that. in Nuget Console you have to provide the connection string and the target migration for the commands: Add-Migration/Update-Database.

Need Code) You can also do that programmatically by using DbMigrator.